# Split path (String) in 3 pieces

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I'm getting a String that represents a path. For testpurposes lets say i'm getting:

```
abc/def/ghi/jkl/....
```

I want to spit that string as follows (the 2 first seperated & the rest combined):

```
Items(0) = "abc"
Items(1) = "def"
Items(2) = "ghi/jkl/..."
```

I opted to use a regex as follows:

```
    Dim someString = "abc/def/ghi/jkl/...."
    Dim Items() As String = Regex.Split(someString, "([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)")
```

But im getting the following output:

```
Items(0) = ""
Items(1) = "abc"
Items(2) = "def"
Items(3) = "ghi/jkl/..."
Items(4) = ""
```

Can someone explain what causes those empty string in the beginning and the end?

I thank you for your time and wish you a pleasant weekend

Comment: did you put in `$` and `^`.

Comment: @DanielA.White . No in fact. is that required to avoid those empty strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) in combination with the [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) method can be a readable and compact alternative to solve this:

```
    Dim text = "abc/def/ghi/jkl/...."

    Dim parts As String() = text.Split("/"c)

    If parts.Count >= 2 Then
        Dim items As String() = {parts.First, parts.Skip(1).First, String.Join("/", parts.Skip(2))}
    End If
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to verify that `parts` has at least three elements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added a check. Actually 2 elements will work too since String.Join has no issue with an empty Enumerable.

Comment: Good idea. But i was hoping for a more "regex-solution". Yet it does solve my problem! Will test it tomorrow at the office

Answer (score 2):

```
(\w+?)\/(\w+?)\/(.*)
```

this should work for your purposes. Just perform a match with this regex and split on capture group 1, 2, and 3.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oO6jK0/1)

Comment: Jeezes that looks 10 times more simple than mine! But i'm still gettings those empty strings